# get excel sheet row id using exceldatareader into dataset

Tags: c#, excel, exceldatareader, excel-reader

I have chosen the ExcelDataReader Library for Reading the .XLS and .XLSX files using C#.
ExcelDataReader is perfectly working with both file formats with my local and deployment server environment.

I'm facing issue, how to get all the row id from given Excel files?

INPUT Excel file:

[image]

And i want output in dataset format like that

[image]

Comment: Can't you infer the row number from the sequence of the data?  That is, wouldn't the first record you read be Row 1, the second Row 2, etc?  You might have to insert the records into the DataSet yourself, from the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Lets explain by code

```
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(Server.MapPath("yourExcelfileName.xlsx"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = ExcelDataReader.ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
        {
            var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
            {
                ConfigureDataTable = a => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                {
                    UseHeaderRow = true
                }
            };
            var dataSet = reader.AsDataSet(conf);
            var sheet = dataSet.Tables["sheetName"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>(); // instead of sheetName you can use Index of it like 0 ,1 , ...
            foreach (var row in sheet)
            {
                // some code
                var rowId = row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(row);
                var rowValueByHeaderFieldName = row["HeaderFieldName"]; // you can also use index instead of HeaderFieldName like row[1] , ...
                // some code
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this help ;)